# font replace in Chrome - font-weight:700 doesn't work

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylus

I do not like Arial font so I want to replace Arial with Ubuntu.
I wrote a code like below in Stylus addon

`@font-face {font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight: 700; src: local('Ubuntu'); }`

or

`@font-face {font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight: 700; src: local('Ubuntu Bold'); }`

In Chrome it does nothing - no change.

But in Firefox everything works great

`@font-face {font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight: 700; src: local('Ubuntu Bold'); }`

and all the Arial bold glyphs are perfectly replaced by Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure neither of the two lines work in Chrome? I found that the first one does work in Chrome and the second one works in Firefox, so that the solution would have been `src: local('Ubuntu Bold'), local('Ubuntu')`. Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/99d5hguf/) just in case. Note that I replaced Ubuntu by DejaVu Sans, since I don't have a font named Ubuntu here and it isn't in the repositories.

Comment: "...found that the first one does work in Chrome..." - sure it works but it is NOT bold.  `@font-face {font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight: bold; src: local('Ubuntu'); }` replaces Arial font to Ubuntu but bold parameter is ignored

Comment: Apparently I hadn't tested in enough environments. It works in Chrome under Linux but not under Windows. Sorry about that. Haven't found a OS-agnostic solution yet.

Comment: Did you import fonts first? I guess Ubuntu font is installed on linux but not windows.